# JPA Single foreign Key ID to refer to two (or more) tables

Tags: java, jpa

Simple question really. This is using JPA on Java and what I what to do is to have a table with and column which can refer to one of two tables. To make this clearer I can have a 'User' table and a 'TempPerson' table. I don't want to pollute my User table (as I use it for security as well, plus has other info as well). Now lets say I have a third table called 'Game'. Now when someone stars a game against someone, they can play against someone in the system already ie. User or someone where they can type a name and new entry for TempPerson is created and used. So the game for player2 (or player1) will be a mapped id to either User.id or TempPerson.id.  Now I understand that a determining column may need to be placed into Game to determine what the Id is for but I hope JPA will cater for it somehow.  Any ideas will be helpful, i could use inheritance but not sure about it.

Here is another example:

Lets say I have a table which holds information about images => id, resolution, width, height, location, bucket .... id_in_the_table_where_used, table_name_of_where_used.  Now, this one table can hold the images for profiles, places, etc... and the profiles, places will have an id referring to the images table, but I also would like the images table to have an id back to where the images is used, which table and which id is using it.

It almost I am asked i 'one to many tables' solution. Although I could have many in between tables etc... Seems overkill to so something quite simple, although many DBAs may be cursing this idea. It does minimise queries, number of tables etc...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use single FK to target multiple tables. You would have to use `@JoinColumn` for that

```
@Entity
public class User{

 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn("universalId", targetEntity=Avatar.class)
 private Avatar

 @oneToMany
 @JoinColumn("universalId", targetEntity=Log.class)
 private List<Log> logs;

}
```

This would use `universalId` column of `User`'s table to lookup related records from `Avatar` and `Log` tables

This however is rather anti-pattern, causing a lot of consequences when for example `universalId` will have to be changed etc. 1 column = 1 FK - go that way.